# TypeError: this.setState is not a function after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, setstate

I'm trying to set the value in the state after 5 secs. But after 5 secs it showing the error at `this.setState({text:false})` line.

**Code snippet**

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        text:true,
        }
      }
 loadtext(){
 setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({text:false});
  },5000)
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: this.setState is not a function

How to solve this?

Comment: Next time please [research your error](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError:+this.setState+is+not+a+function+site:stackoverflow.com) - I could not even save your question after changing the title to the error because it already existed

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `loadtext` foo

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.loadtext = this.loadtext.bind(this); // here change
    this.state={
        text:true,
    }
 }

 loadtext() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({text:false});
    }, 5000)
 }
```

Comment: [Huge dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=TypeError:+this.setState+is+not+a+function+site:stackoverflow.com)